# SQL - Return average age depending on visits?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out this task, but after trying and trying i am not able to solve it. Can someone with more SQL experience help me out?

I have 3 tables:

[image]

[[image]

[image]

**The task is to calculate the average age (alter) from each person who visited a restaurant located in Salzburg. If a person visited a restaurant that is located in Salzburg twice, it should be added to the average age (Emily in this case).**

Since Piccolo and Stella are located in Salzburg, 4 visits happen overall.

But how do i pull this off in SQL?

How do i count the visits?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance everyone!

MySQL Version: 8.0.20 
Using MySQL Workbench.

EDIT 4:

Was able to find the solution on my own more or less, although the answer from @Nick is awesome as well, which is why i accept his answer as correct.
Thank you all so much and @Nick! 
Just in case someone runs into the same issue,
my final solution is:

```
SELECT (AVG(age)) FROM PERSON INNER JOIN ISST ON PERSON.person_name = ISST.person_name INNER JOIN PIZZERIA ON ISST.pizzeria_name = PIZZERIA.pizzeria_name && PIZZERIA.stadt="Salzburg";
```

Comment: Please tag your DBMS, version included.

Comment: Please add the `mysql` tag, try to include schemas/data as text, and show the code if any you have tried so far.

Comment: Updated the version number.

Comment: When you add it read please https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I've added another example for another task were i was able to solve it on my own. Maybe this gives you an idea what i need to do? I am completely lost on how to sum up the amount of visits per person to a restaurant and then calculate the avg out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to calculate the average age of *all* visitors (regardless of whether a person visits a pizzeria in the same city twice), you can just `JOIN` your visits table to the pizzeria and person tables and average the results:

```
SELECT AVG(p.alter)
FROM ISST i
JOIN PIZZERIA z ON z.pizzeria_name = i.pizzeria_name
JOIN PERSON p ON p.person_name = i.person_name
WHERE z.stadt = 'Salzburg'
```

Output:

```
25.75
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2HP3ehdJDBgqJu2E1bdMhG/0)

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your answer. See my updated post. So if a person visits a restaurant twice, the age should be added to the average age. Emily visits a restaurant twice that is located in Salzburg, which means her age must be added twice to calculate the average age of all visitors.

Comment: @Prometheus this query does that. See the demo - the output is 25.75 which is (23 + 23 + 26 + 31)/4

Comment: Awesome i'll check it out. I came up with a solution as well, i update my post, the only thing is missing is the avg, would you like to change my updated code so that i can get the avg out of it as well? You can leave your original answer here as well, as i want to study your solution. Only if you don't mind, thanks for taking your time.

Comment: Thanks for adding dbfiddle, so awesome.

Comment: Okay, all i had to do was to change SUM to AVG and it works as well. Sorry for the absolute obvious questions, started uni and this prof is serious about databases i guess.

Comment: @Prometheus sorry I wasn't around to answer your comments, I had to go to a meeting. I'm glad you've got an answer that works for you.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you took the time to help. Thanks and have a great day!